# Angular 2+ multiple applications/sites

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile

I have to think this is a unique situation. 
My company has three apps.  App1, App2, and App3. 
Really these apps were just websites that were build for mobile devices.
(Html, Javascript, Css).  With Angular JS to link them all together.
Some of the apps had similar pages, and so shared the same code. Different html, but same javascript (controller).

The first version really was just a webview on the phone.

In Sept 2017 we added cordova to the mix.  Cordova wants to wrap the code.
We fixed this by just having a cordova folder for each app.  In each folder there is a www folder that cordova uses.  We just symlinked this back to the web code.  The downside was each cordova app got all the files from app1, app2, and app3.

Next our company bought another company that does similar type of services.  They didn't want to affect those customers, so it was decided to just reuse our apps but with another logo and colors.

So now App1  need to have App1-company1. App1-company2.  App2-company1, App2-company2. 
With Cordova this was too bad,  we build a new login page. do some new styles for other parts of the app (that we set dynamically).  In Cordova we tell it the start page,  the app builds all files still but a new start page, new app.

We thought maybe we might have time to move off of Angular JS  to something else. The only other framework we were familiar with was angular 2+ with Ionic to take care of the cordova stuff.

I am slowly seeing that Angular 2 does not build websites like we did before. It doesn't seems to like to share files as much as a website did before.

I am still learning Angular 2, so I'm trying to figure out how to setup angular 2 to be able to have multiple apps?

We started down the path of each app was its own angular 2 app/project.
But wasn't sure how to use that with other companies?

I don't know if I can setup different html pages.  instead of index.html.  have app1Index.html
This in turn would point to other versions like src/app1/app1.app.module.ts which would load the components for app1?
Same with app2.

This would solve my first problem of trying to share code.  I could use the same components in multiple places.

I don't know if I could do this with the reskin of our apps.   app1-company2.html and app1-company2.module.ts.

Not sure if that can be solved with angular 2?

Maybe VueJs can handle this better?

Answer (score 1):

VueJS is very good at sharing code. 
One option would be to use something like Vue Custom Element for your vuejs project containing the components.

https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element

This will allow you to write your components and then use webpack to package them up into files. I think this pretty much works out of the box if you install the vue-webpack boilerplate to create your 'component library'

[VueWebpack Boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)

You can then include your packaged files (js, css etc) into your projects where you want to use your components. This can be done by simple src reference in your index.html file or you could publish them via npm and install them that way. The choice is yours.